# Time.zone.now not working in Rails database (Learn enough tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Steps to reproduce

Greetings everyone. I am currently on chapter 11 of the Ruby on Rails tutorial. At the moment I am trying to get the Time.zone.now to work.

On the console, everything is working when I enter Time.zone.now

```
2.4.0 :007 > Time.zone.now
=> Fri, 23 Jun 2017 22:34:33 UTC +00:00


class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      # (1) time set to a variable
      time = Time.zone.now 
      user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      # (2) This time variable results to year 2000
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, time) 
      log_in user
      # (3) This time variable results to year 2017
      flash[:success] = "Account activated! #{time}"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

#### Where it breaks down

The follow is an output when I enter User.last on the rails console

```
 => #<User id: 110, name: "foo", email: "foo@email.com", created_at: "2017-06-23 22:28:09", updated_at: "2017-06-23 22:28:21",...., activated: true, activated_at: "2000-01-01 22:28:21"> 
2.4.0 :009 >
```

As you can see, the activated_at shows the correct time but not the correct year, day, and month. 
However, the same time variable is used as a flash message noted above as comment (3).

[result form: flash[:success] = "Account activated! #{time}" (comment 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFg6l.png)

Any ideas?

#### What I have attempted

All I have been able to try is a mixture of the following configurations in the config/application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
    # config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

  end
end
```

Comment: Just a guess. Can it happening because you have not set any time zone for Rails ? Can you try setting it applictaion.rb like `config.time_zone = 'Hawaii'`. If this did not work then try setting it in action, like : `Time.zone = 'Hawaii' ;  time = Time.zone.now`.

Comment: Why are you setting `time_zone_aware_types` and `default_timezone`?

Comment: @Sajan I so instead of all of these:   config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
I should try: [config.time_zone = 'Hawaii'] ?

Comment: @jdgray Yeah you are right, that was a mistake on my part. but I have tried setting just one of config.active_record.* options and none work. It is weird because my users "created_at" shows the right date but the "activated_at" does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with the column type in your database.  I'm unsure of your what database you're using, however I've seen this before when the database column type is `time` and not `datetime`.

Check your `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql` and confirm the type of the `activated_at` column.

Behind the scenes postgres and mysql store timestamp values as seconds before or after midnight 2000-01-01.

Comment: Exactly correct... I wrote datatime instead of datetime. 

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. If you don't mind clicking the check mark next to the answer, this will help other users with a similar problem find what worked for you. Thanks!